# Why does not read in a Struct with a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I've got this code, and for some reason the cin.get does not assign a value to the p.name[i]. I don't know why, but getline does not work aswell. I've tried to just cin.get(temp,30), to read a temp, but this dont work in the for cycle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct echip
{
    char name[30];
    double price;
};

void read(echip* p, int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name: ";

        cin.get((p + i)->name, 30);
        cin.ignore();

        cout << (p + i)->name;

        cout << "Price: "; cin >> (p+i)->price;
        cout << (p+i)->price;
    }
}

int main()
{
    echip* k;
    int n;

    cout << "Number: "; cin >> n;
    k = new echip[n];

    read(k, n);

    delete[] k;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why C-strings, if you have the `<string>` header included? Your code cannot be compiled by others, I think. `citire()` is used, but not shown. You don't even call the read function that you show.

Comment: It can make sense if you want a fixed length struct

Comment: I think `citire` == `read` - but not sure.

Comment: @ErwanDaniel so what should I do? write echip* [10]?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't rename the function in the main.

Comment: Avoid doing `(p + i)->name` when `p[i].name` is way easier to read. You can also kick ahead the `p` pointer each iteration and just do `p->name` as well. Even better: Use `std::vector<echip>` and `for (auto& echip : echips)` on a `const std::vector<echip>& echips` argument.

Comment: You need `cin.ignore();` *before* the `get`, or the newline from the previous `cin` is still in the input buffer (and it stays in the input stream for other reads).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `cin.ignore()` before the `cin.get()`:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r1dh74iqU)

```
#include<limits>
//...

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //here  
    cin.get((p + i)->name, 30);           

    cout << (p + i)->name;
    cout << "Price: "; 

    cin >> (p+i)->price;
    cout << (p+i)->price;
}
```

`cin.get()`, unlike `cin` with operator `>>`, will not ignore newline characters.

Some other minor issues I think is relevant to mention:

- In C++ `struct`s don't need to be `typedef`'d.
- C++ has standard containers that can be used instead of C-style ones in this case [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) would be a good option.
- `Using namespace std;` [is not considered a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6865932).

Comment: I know all these.
I used typdef because I thought that this way I can solve it.

Comment: @Pilv, oh, I see, it's nice to see you tried to solve it before asking, it's actually part of the site's guidelines, anyway, if you don't mind I would keep the minor issues section so that future readers can learn from this post and for overall completion of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do `cin.ignore()` after numeric input.

```
cout << "Number: "; cin >> n; cin.ignore();
```

and

```
cout << "Price: "; cin >> (p+i)->price; cin.ignore();
```

Don't do `cin.ignore()` after `get` or `getline`.

Better still don't mix up get/getline and >>, then you don't have to do ignore at all.

Comment: @Pilv But really if you want to read lines, use getline, don't use >>. Read a line and then if you want a number convert the line to a number.